# Как можно обезопасить метод удаления данных?

Tags: php

Есть следующий код, задача которого удалить данные из бд. Сейчас все данные удаляются при переходе по ссылке localhost/?id=666. Понимаю что это говнокод, и не понимаю как можно сделать правильно. Направьте пожалуйста)

```
public $id;
public function __construct() {
    $this->id = $_GET['id'];
}
public function delete() {
    $dbh = Db::getConnect();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '$this->id'");
    $sth->execute();       
}
```

И html ссылка:

```
<a href="<?php echo '?id='.$post['id'] ?>" name="id">del</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

В целом другого особо не дано.

Есть два варианта:

1) Это просто по ссылке

2) Через форму, в которой можно еще передать csrf токен.

**(Добавлено: через форму более правильный вариант чем через ссылку; методы DELETE или POST, не GET)**

Главное, чтобы данный функционал был закрыт от пользователей, которым он не должен быть доступен. Если, например всего один админ на сайте, и других пользователей не предполагается - то достаточно обычной авторизации.

Если есть несколько ролей - то разделение по ролям.

В общем основной посыл - так удалять это нормально, главное защитить от внешнего посягательства.

Единственная серьезная логическая ошибка - вы делаете подготовленный запрос, но пихаете в него сырые данные. Это бессмыслица.  Надо подготавливать запрос с плейсхолдером, а потом сетить параметры.

Примерно как то так:

```
$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$dbh->bind_param("d", $this->id);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: а то что данные удаляются через GET-запрос вас нисколько не смутило?

Comment: А что тут должно смущать? HTTP методы между собой не имеют практически никаких преимуществ в безопасности.  Нельзя подделать post? или delete? Если взломают админку - разницы не будет какой метод.

Comment: у каждого HTTP_метода есть свое предназначение, и get явно не предназначен для удаления, что очевидно даже из его названия. про непосредственно безопасность тут речь не идет.

Comment: @teran в теории да, но между собой они отличаются лишь первичным заголовком. Например php имеет из коробки только глобальные массивы post и get, и как бы в теории ничего из этого не подходит для удаления. Писать парсер заголовка для самописа, только чтобы следовать теории? Да и put нет.

Comment: есть не теория а HTTP RFC, который говорит, что GET/HEAD запросы не должны использоваться для каких-либо действий кроме получения данных.  Так что надо следовать здравому смыслу, и использовать POST. и отличаются они не только заголовком.

Comment: @teran ну по большей части с вами соглашусь. Забыл что Get запрос - идемпотентный и POST подходил бы больше. Хотя ничего критичного кроме теории нет. Если полностью следовать RFC - то POST для добавления данных и он не подходит для удаления.